# PouchDB sync authorization?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

How do I ensure that the current user has authorization to access a CouchDB database via PouchDB?  From my experimentation, calling the new PouchDB() method with the CouchDB database name grants you access to that data.

Setting require_valid_user to true in Futon seems to work, but the Futon modal window still pops up after authenticating the user via POST /_session.  I want to have a standard login screen (username and password) that logs the user into my application and grants access to the correct CouchDB database (via PouchDB).  I can I do this?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to check out this plugin https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication

Answer (score 9):

There is a PouchDB plugin built by Nolan Lawson that provides PouchDb with an authentication API:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://mysite:5984/mydb');
db.login('batman', 'brucewayne').then(function (batman) {
  console.log("I'm Batman.");
  return db.logout();
});
```

Here are the methods it mixes in:

- signup
- login
- logout
- getSession
- getUser

To prevent browser HTTP basic authentication modal dialogs of ye olde times, we have to be subtle in the way we use PouchDB. To prevent a rouge unauthenticated request to CouchDB (used to check whether the remote DB exists), pass skipSetup: true in Pouch's constructor options. Secondly, to authenticate the request against _session, add the HTTP basic authorization header to db.login()'s AJAX options.

```
var user = {
  name: 'admin',
  password: 'admin'
};

var pouchOpts = {
  skip_setup: true
};

var ajaxOpts = {
  ajax: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa(user.name + ':' + user.password)
    }
  }
};

var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/test', pouchOpts);

db.login(user.name, user.password, ajaxOpts).then(function() {
  return db.allDocs();
}).then(function(docs) {
  console.log(docs);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: the `skipSetup` property has been changed to `skip_setup`

Answer (score 0):

i use pouchdb-authentication for sync

```
 npm i pouchdb-authentication
```

plugin import

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));
```

code:

```
var localDb = new PouchDB('mydatabase');
var remoteDb = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/mydatabase', {skip_setup: true});

remoteDb.login(username, password).then(function () {
  localDb.sync(remoteDb, {live: true, retry: true, /* other sync options */});
});
```